# Gwenview is too slow to load image from a directory containing many images

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, plasma-5, gwenview

Gwenview takes a lot of time (sometimes 15+ seconds to load a 4 mb jpg file) to load an image from a directory where there are lot of images. This is probably because it tries to load all the images in the background, as after loading one, I can view all other images (by clicking arrow keys) without any lag.
When there is only one image file in a directory, it loads very quickly.

Is there any way to tell Gwenview to only load the image it was asked to?

Comment: Can someone else reproduce this behaviour in a computer without ssd?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1408991/1699391 thanks @ziabadar....this solved for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible (by now?) to make Gwenview start fast by changing settings in the GUI. But probably this actually does something similar to the known workarounds, because the behavior after this change is a bit silly (see below).

Here you go:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to make the menu appear
2. Go to `Settings`, then `Configure Gwenview...`
3. Click on `Advanced`
4. Enable `Low resource usage mode`

This will delete all thumbnails and deactivate the generation of thumbnails. Afterwards, Gwenview should be fast.

Caveat: From now on, Gwenview will actively delete all existing thumbnails. This means that applications like Dolphin will be slow showing thumbnails, because they have to be generated first.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Check if your disk is low in free space. IF YES, Try Empty space.
2. Check if RAM is small.
3. Try to split small number of images in separate folders.
4. Also see if the file explorer like dolphin/ Nemo is also taking too much time opening these large images.
5. Try disabling animations in settings

This may Help you: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=164924

Also in another post one suggested set desktop as folder and not as a desktop solved the issue.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: 7 gb of free space in the partition, 4 gb of RAM. Suggetion 3. Will make it fast, but I want to keep these pictures in the same folder, and precisely why I am asking the question. Dolphin is fast. Animation in Gwenview settings? It looks like it is slow because it loads all the images when asked to load one, and this is not related to animations. This is because once one image is loaded, I can access all other images in the same directory at once.

Comment: This may Help you:  https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=164924                                                 Also in another post one suggested set desktop as folder and not as a desktop solved the issue.

Comment: @Ajay This workround makes Gwenview fast, but removes the ability to save thumbnails. As a result the computer keeps generating thumbnails every time any folder is opened.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it's because of gwenview creates thumbnails for all images in folder, but not loads them all into memory (only one by one per thread as I think). In case of thumbnails creation, it uses hard drive and CPU mostly. But check it yourself and attach some graphs to see what happens during its operation. Most likely you access slow storage. Have you tried to open image in folder with large number of images from SSD?

Comment: @Gryu I don't have an SSD. Yes, it uses the hard drive and CPU, but not much RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I have found so far is based on https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=164924, which was there in Ajay's comment.

Since Gwenview tries to create thumbnails of all images in the folder, it may take a lot of time to do so in a slower HDD. The workaround is to disable its access to thumbnail folder by changing its owner to root.

It can be done by following these steps.

1. `rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/*` (deletes all previously generated thumbnails)
2. `sudo chmod 555 ~/.cache/thumbnails` (makes the folder owned by root)

Note that now the computer will generate thumbnails every time any folder is opened, but it does not make it noticeably slow, and gwenview has a fast startup time. One can further disable thumbnails for certain extensions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this ridiculous problem (opening an image in Gwenview takes much more time than firing up GIMP…) was to get rid of Gwenview and replace it with [Nomacs](https://nomacs.org/).

Comment: Also have a look at https://interversehq.com/qview/ It is amazingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

for me installing `qt5-imageformats` solved the problem, In my case gwenview was stuck on loading image...

Answer (score 0):

There is some code / resource sharing with the Dolphin file manager. As such, if Dolphin is suck in something, it impacts Gwenview. For instance I had forgotten a remote ssh directory open in a Dolphin Tab, using the `fish://user@address/directory/subdirectory` protocol, but that machine was offline at the time. It caused a 30s delay every time I launched Gwenview (but subsequent images were not impacted). I closed the Dolphin tab and things were back to normal.

Maybe you have a similar situation.